# My map looks wierd and “pixly” in OL3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to present a mapserver with OL3, it doesnt work well. The documentation of the mapserver is non-existent and the GetCapabilities to the mapserver responds with a very short (not so good or usefull) answer.

I have managed to present the map, but it looks very weird, quite pixly. A picture says more then thousand words, so I'll just present to you how it looks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP1e3.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/buEG7.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTRQx.jpg

And I even did a JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qpz7bp2g/

```
var oLayers = "ST:background";

    var oURL = "its on the jsfiddle";

    var oProjection = "EPSG:3006";

    var oScales = [4000,8000,15000,30000,90000, 120000, 180000, 250000, 500000];

    var screenDPI = 95;
    var IPM = 39.37;

    var resolutions = [];
    for (var i = oScales.length-1; i >= 0;--i) {
        resolutions.push(oScales[i] / (screenDPI * IPM));
    }

    var extent=[181896.33,6101648.07,864582.51,7688373.92];

    var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: oProjection,
        units: "m",
        extent: extent
    });

    //ol.proj.addProjection(projection);

    var layers = [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            extent: extent,
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: oURL,
                params: {'LAYERS':oLayers,
                'SRS' : "EPSG:3006"}
            })
        })
    ];


    var view = new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        center: ol.proj.transform([13.0, 55.6], 'EPSG:4326', oProjection),
        resolutions: resolutions,
        extent: extent,
        zoom: 0
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: layers,
        target: 'maps',
        view: view
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WMS `GetMap` URL looks OK:

```
http://gis.skanetrafiken.se/wmspublic/service/wms?
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.3.0&
REQUEST=GetMap&
FORMAT=image%2Fpng&
TRANSPARENT=true&
LAYERS=ST%3Abackground&
SRS=EPSG%3A3006&
WIDTH=640&
HEIGHT=640&
STYLES=&
BBOX=405029.65265624993%2C6138836.957109375%2C417425.94835937495%2C6151233.2528125
```

[Link](http://gis.skanetrafiken.se/wmspublic/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=ST%3Abackground&SRS=EPSG%3A3006&WIDTH=640&HEIGHT=640&STYLES=&BBOX=405029.65265624993%2C6138836.957109375%2C417425.94835937495%2C6151233.2528125).

But this is what the WMS server renders:

[image: This is what the WMS server renders]

So I guess the problem is not OL but rather styling configuration on the server. Or maybe you may need to figure out the suitable zoom levels. Is there a working and good looking solution using the same WMS server? Check their zoom levels.